# How to cast a custom model dropdownlist into a selectlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a collection of data coming back from a call in my Controller for a dropdown list as follows:

```
ViewData["statuses"] = db.GetStatuses();
```

It is of type "YeagerTechModel.Status[]".

I'm getting the following error when I try and list that data in my view inside a simple dropdown list:

```
Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'YeagerTechModel.Status[]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[YeagerTechModel.Status[]]'
```

My view is set up as follows:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddSingleStatus", "Status", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="display-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => Model.Description);
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.Description, new SelectList((List<YeagerTechModel.Status[]>)ViewData["statuses"], "StatusID", "Description"));
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.Description)
                </div>
            </td>
           </tr> 
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value='@Resources.Add' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
```

**How can I properly cast the collection coming back into a simple dropdown list?**

Comment: Instead of casting it to a `List<YeagerTechModel.Status[]>` try just casting it to `YeagerTechModel.Status[]`.  Arrays implement IEnumerable so it should be fine passing it to the `SelectList`.

Comment: How can I give you credit for this for the points???

Comment: I'll post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of casting it to a `List<YeagerTechModel.Status[]>` try just casting it to `YeagerTechModel.Status[]`. Arrays implement `IEnumerable` so it should be fine passing it to the `SelectList`.